# Fill TableView with data from MySql

Tags: php, mysql, xcode

I have a TableView which load data from MySQL using PHP file. What I am trying to do is to fill the Table with 50 records and then when the users pull up then the next 50 records will load and so on.

I have no idea to do it. Can you guide me or tell me how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: you mean is 'lazy load' ?

Comment: Yes, to load a part of the data

Comment: maybe this [tutorial link](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/) will help.

Comment: What you have sent is with html, my problem with TableView in Xcode